# Double coset spaces of reductive groups and integral representations of L-functions

Tags: rt.representation-theory, nt.number-theory, automorphic-forms, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be a reductive group over a number field $k$, with center $Z$. Let $P$ be a parabolic subgroup. Let $H$ be a reductive subgroup of $G$. To what extent can we understand the double coset space $P_k\backslash G_k/H_k$? I'll give some examples, then my motivation for the question, and then I'll refine the question.

Let's look at some simple examples.

Example 1: $G=GL_2$, $P$ is the standard Borel subgroup, $H=Z\cdot GL_1$, embedded as the Levi component of $P$. Using the Bruhat decomposition, $P_k\backslash G_k/H_k=1\cup w\cup wn$, where $n$ is any nontrivial element of the unipotent radical of $P$, and $w$ is the nontrivial element of the Weyl group of $G$.

Example 2: $G=GL_2$, $P$ is the standard Borel subgroup, $H$ is the multiplicative group of a quadratic extension $k_1$ of $k$. Identifying $P_k\backslash G_k$ with $k^2-(0,0)=k_1^\times$, we see that $P_k\backslash G_k/H_k=1$.

Example 3: $G=GL_2\times GL_2$, $P$ is $B\times B$, the product of the Borel subgroups of $GL_2$, $H$ is $GL_2$ embedded diagonally in $G$. Then 
$P_k\backslash G_k/H_k=B_k\backslash H_k/B_k=1\cup w$.

Example 4: $G=GL_2$ over a quadratic extension $k_1$ of $k$ (considered as a $k$-group), $P$ the standard Borel subgroup, $H=GL_2$ over $k$. Identifying $P_k\backslash G_k$ with $k_1^2-(0,0)$, we see that $P_k\backslash G_k/H_k=1\cup wn_\alpha$, where $n_\alpha=\bigg(\matrix{1&\alpha\cr 0&1}\bigg)$ and $\alpha$ generates $k_1$ over $k$.

---

So why do I care?
One of the primary sources of integral representations of automorphic $L$-functions is integrating the restriction of an Eisenstein series on a group $G$, associated to a parabolic subgroup $P$, against a cusp form on a subgroup $H$, i.e. 
$$Z(s,f)=\int_{Z_{\mathbb A} H_k\backslash H_{\mathbb A} } E_s(h)f(h)\ dh$$
In order for this to converge, we need $Z\backslash Z_H$ to be anisotropic (so, e.g., Example 1 won't work without modification). Unwinding the Eisenstein series, we have 
$$Z(s,f)=\sum_{\xi\in P_k\backslash G_k/H_k}\int_{Z_{\mathbb A}  \Theta^\xi_k\backslash H_{\mathbb A} }\varepsilon_s(\xi h)f(h)\ dh$$
where $\Theta^\xi=\xi^{-1}P\xi\cap H$. Let's consider a fixed term in the sum. 
$$\int_{Z_{\mathbb A}  \Theta^\xi_k\backslash H_{\mathbb A} }\varepsilon(\xi h)f(h)\ dh=\int_{Z_{\mathbb A}  \Theta^\xi_{\mathbb A} \backslash H_{\mathbb A} }\int_{Z_{\mathbb A}  \Theta^\xi_k\backslash\Theta^\xi_{\mathbb A} }\varepsilon_s(\xi\theta h)f(\theta h)\delta_{\Theta_{\mathbb A} }(\theta)^{-1}\ d\theta\ dh$$
$$=\int_{Z_{\mathbb A}  \Theta^\xi_{\mathbb A} \backslash H_{\mathbb A} }\int_{Z_{\mathbb A}  \Theta^\xi_k\backslash\Theta^\xi_{\mathbb A} }\varepsilon_s(\xi\theta\xi^{-1}\xi h)f(\theta h)\delta_{\Theta_{\mathbb A} }(\theta)^{-1}\ d\theta\ dh$$
$$=\int_{Z_{\mathbb A}  \Theta^\xi_{\mathbb A} \backslash H_{\mathbb A} }\varepsilon_s(\xi h)\int_{Z_{\mathbb A}  \Theta^\xi_k\backslash\Theta^\xi_{\mathbb A} }\varepsilon_s(\xi\theta\xi^{-1})f(\theta h)\delta_{\Theta_{\mathbb A} }(\theta)^{-1}\ d\theta\ dh$$
Note that if $\varepsilon_s(\xi\theta\xi^{-1})$ is trivial on $\Theta^\xi_{\mathbb A} $ and $\Theta^\xi$ has a normal subgroup that is a unipotent radical of a parabolic subgroup of $H$, the term vanishes by the cuspidality of $f$.

Under certain conditions, the inner integral (and hence the entire integral) factors into a product of local integrals, which we can hopefully compute to be local factors of an automorphic $L$-function. But we must pass over this in silence. (See [Garrett's](http://math.umn.edu/~garrett/m/v/) Euler Factorization of Global Integrals for more.)

---

In order to make further progress, we would need to understand the nature of $\Theta^\xi$, as well. Let's calculate it for the above examples.

Example 1: $\Theta^1=H$, $\Theta^w=H$, $\Theta^{wn}=Z$.

Example 2: $\Theta^1=Z$.

Example 3: $\Theta^1=B$, $\Theta^w=w^{-1}Bw$ (the "opposite" Borel subgroup).

Example 4: $\Theta^1$ is the Borel subgroup of $H$, $\Theta^{wn_\alpha}=k_1^\times$.

Another very interesting example is the set-up for the triple product $L$-function, found in either section 3.10 of Bump's book or in [PS-Rallis](http://www.numdam.org/numdam-bin/item?id=CM_1987__64_1_31_0), Rankin triple L functions.

It would be really nice to know, given $G$, $P$, and $H$, what automorphic $L$-function (if any, since most such triples won't produce anything interesting) is represented by the above integral. Hypothetically, we could make a list of the $L$-functions, like there is for the Langlands-Shahidi method. Understanding the double coset decomposition is the first step.

This is probably way too much to hope for; I'm interested in understanding why it is so hard.
It seems that, over $\mathbb C$, we know when the double coset is finite (at least when $H_{\mathbb C}$ is an open subgroup of the fixed points of an involution of $G_{\mathbb C}$). I can't find a good statement of what is known over $\mathbb Q$. Is anything known if $G$ and $H$ are split? Or if $G$ is split and $H$ is anisotropic? Or if $G=GL_n$? Etc . . .

Comment: You may find S.P.Wang and A.G.Helminck's paper 'on rationality properties of involutions of reductive groups' helpful, in which they showed that when $H_k$ is an open subgroup of the fixed point of an involution of $G_k$, then the double coset $P_k\G_k/H_k$ is finite when $k$ is a local field. When $k$ is global, they also gave an example with infinite double cosets. 

Comment: Thanks! I see that Helminck has a lot of interesting papers on his website. Proposition 6.10 in the paper you mention seems to simplify the double-coset calculation to something more tractable:  

Let $A_i$ be representatives of the $H_k$-conjugacy classes of $\theta$-stable maximal $k$-split tori in $G$, then
$$H_k\backslash G_k/P_k=\bigcup_{i\in I} W_{H_k}(A_i)\backslash W_{G_k}(A_i)$$
here $H$ is a $k$-open subgroup of the fixed points of the involution $\theta$ and $P$ is a minimal parabolic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a very nice question!

All of your examples are spherical quotients. Please take a look at
[Sakellaridis - Spherical varieties and integral representations of $L$-functions](https://web.archive.org/web/20120714064540/http://andromeda.rutgers.edu/%7Esakellar/rs.pdf) and Yiannis' other papers
for connections between spherical quotients and integral representations for L functions.

Comment: That's very interesting! If I understand correctly, the idea here is to replace the Eisenstein series with a function (called an $X$-Eisenstein series) that are constructed to unwind into specific period integrals which we can hopefully understand. In effect, it turns the question I'm asking on it's head: instead of asking what period integrals we can obtain by integrating an Eisenstein series, we ask how to continue the $X$-Eisenstein series that gives rise to a period integral.